# space tower in python with loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7         7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6             6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5                 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4                     4 3 2 1
1 2 3                         3 2 1
1 2                             2 1
1                                 1
```

How can I code this in python?

So far this is my code but I can't figure out the spaces.

```py
number = int(input("enter a number to create your triangle: "))

for col in range(number,0,-1):
    for row in range(1,col):
        print(row,  end=" ")

    if col<number:
        print(" "*(row*2), end="")
        
    for row in range(col-1,0,-1):
        print(row, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: indentation is messed up. edit your code in the question

Comment: Using unpacking you can make it quite easy. [Code](https://tio.run/##NYzBDsIgEETv/YoJJxZpInrRJn4MGlQSBbKBQ78et6Hubfa9mbLWd07nS@HeU/veA@OGmKqOqbSqVUhVXh47qxkPDr4GrLlJ5OjT6xMWKKKp8Fak6ZkZUUbAAoMeVYujxexomSA3VDMEZ0U/wJGF0QoKBnpvYUYkySfa4NDjf4p6v/4A).

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Maybe helpful to know you can make a string from numbers like `s = ' '.join(map(str, range(1, i)))`, You can reverse that string with `s[::-1]`.

Comment: I am only having problem with adding the space, basically it is row/number * 2 but can not implement it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping multiple times, you could create a base list containing all numbers as strings, iterate once to print each row and the reverse:

```
number = 9

base = [str(n) for n in range(1, number+1)]
for i, idx in enumerate(range(len(base)-1, 0, -1)):
    if i == 0:
        print(' '.join(base + base[::-1]))
    base[idx] = ' '
    print(' '.join(base + base[::-1]))
```

Out:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7         7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6             6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5                 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4                     4 3 2 1
1 2 3                         3 2 1
1 2                             2 1
1                                 1
```

Comment: thanks you!  isn't base python 2.x content? I haven't come across in 3.x

Comment: @user21090275: Works in Py2 and Py3

Answer (score 0):

As I've pointed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75253095/10824407#comment132791998_75253095) comment, using all "power" of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) you can make it really easy.

By default all arguments passed to `print()` will be separated with space, so we can just unpack there range from `1` to current index, string of spaces and reverse range from current index to `1`:

```py
number = int(input("enter a number to create your triangle: "))

for i, n in enumerate(range(number, 0, -1)):
    print(*range(1, n + 1), *(" " * (i * 2)), *range(n, 0, -1))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7         7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6             6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5                 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4                     4 3 2 1
1 2 3                         3 2 1
1 2                             2 1
1                                 1
```

**Important notice:** Code above will work properly only for number *below `10`*.